# Increase size of FireMonkey TSpeedButton image

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Using a `FireMonkey` `TspeedButton` on a form for a cross platform app, when setting the property `StyleLookup` to use `cameratoolbutton` is there any way of changing the size of this image, I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this, but all based on using stylebook.

First, simplest way - edit `cameratoolbutton` style in stylebook:

1. Load style into stylebook and open it
2. Scroll to `cameratoolbutton` item in `Structure` panel

[image]

3. Find `icon` subitem and change it's properties in `Object Inspector`. For example, you can change `Align` (`Client` by default) and `WrapMode` (`Center` by default)

Second way - do it in runtime. Add `OnApplyStyleLookup` event handler to button and write code to work with style items:

```pascal
procedure THeaderFooterForm.btn2ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  obj: TFmxObject;
begin
  obj:=TFmxObject(Sender).FindStyleResource('icon'); // use StyleName of inner object (see prev. picture)
  if Assigned(obj) and (obj is TStyleObject) then // TStyleObject is class of "icon"  (see prev. picture)
    TStyleObject(obj).WrapMode:=TImageWrapMode.Stretch;
end;
```

**Note 1**: by default, you can't change size of `cameratoolbutton`, because when you run program, it's size returns to hardcoded values. If you need this, you must do next workaround:

1. Save your style from stylebook in `.style` file
2. Open this file in any text editor (Notepad++, for example)
3. Find next strings

> ```
> object TLayout
>   StyleName = 'cameratoolbutton'
>   Visible = False
>   TabOrder = 160
>   FixedWidth = 44
>   FixedHeight = 44
> ```

4. Remove `FixedXXX` strings and save file
5. Load changed file to stylebook

**Note 2**: style uses bitmaps, so if you need large/small picture, perhaps, you should use your own images

Comment: the event handler way doesn't seem to work with Delphi 11, it keeps on showing a small version of the icon